# inserting Datetime into SQLCE with milliseconds C#

Tags: c#, datetime, format, sql-server-ce

I have a string datetime in this format "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff"

like so..

```
DateTime mydate = Convert.ToDateTime("13-09-2010 02:30:14.905"); 
 result.SetValue(1, mydate);
```

//I get a error saying 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime'

if i do it this way

```
DateTime mydate = DateTime.ParseExact("13-09-2010 02:30:14.905", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
 result.SetValue(1, mydate);
```

it works fine but formats it without the milliseconds.

i just need the datetime object to hold my formatted time so i can insert it.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is? You *appear* to have answered yourself in your question?

Answer (score 4):

`DateTime` doesn't hold a "formatted time" - it just holds a time. It's like `int` doesn't hold a "hex value" or a "decimal value" - it just holds an integer.

Your second version is almost certainly parsing all the data correctly - print it out to check - so it's the database interaction that's causing the problems, I suspect. You can isolate the parsing from the database interaction by explicitly constructing a `DateTime` value for a test program, of course.

You should be aware that according to the [SQL Server CE 3.5 docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172424(v=SQL.100).aspx), the datetime type in SQL Server CE only supports a granularity of one three-hundredth of a second, i.e. just over 3ms. If you need an *exact* millisecond value, you may want to consider an alternative representation (e.g. a datetime accurate to the second, and a separate integer field for milliseconds.)

Comment: well its just a datetime column. for some reason the second version is excluding the milliseconds before it is even inserted. it adds slashes and formats it like this 9/13/2010 3:12:22 AM if i convert it back to a string

Comment: Make sure that when you convert it back to string, you specify a custom format with ".fff" for milliseconds. The default DateTime.ToString does not include them AFAIK.

Comment: ok i think i understand it now. if it doesnt sort right i will just store the damn time as a int and sort it that way,